# Проблема с кэшом в Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

Есть абсолютно работающий php-скрипт, работающий в связке с Imagick (Image Magick)

И вот совсем недавно начали появляться ошибки подобного рода:

```
Message: unable to open pixel cache `/home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html/files/upload/4/16/3833fea4b784314332072c2178d78a45': No such file or directory @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3998
```

Проблема возникла после того как я почистил папку /tmp (Ubuntu, место на сервере забилось)

Я думаю что при этом удалил папку для кэш-файлов Imagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решилась путем презагрузки Apache